# Music when Luffy first used haki against Fujitora?

Tags: one-piece, music

In the Dressrosa arc there is a scene where Luffy is carrying Law and Fujitora steps in front of him.

Luffy then drops him, coats his right arm and takes a stance. During this scene there is a track that plays but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I'll be back later to add the following information:

- Episode name and number
- Youtube clip of the scene I am referring to

But if anyone knows off hand, please let me know? I'd like to find an OST version of it but I can't seem to locate the track name.

It's episode 683 
`With a Rumbling of the Ground - The God of Destruction, Giant Pica Descends`
Here is the youtube clip

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rorWM9d5F9g

Music plays from 0:55-1:21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The track is called Preemptive Strike you can find it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gpt9sSs4qOA

I have pasted the website that allowed me to find this OST below, it could be useful to use in the future:
http://onepiecetracklist.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link and the source. I'll use that in the future for other one piece related themes